# Rails 3 + Jquery click nothing happen on first click

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

i have a problem with my jquery but unable to find why.
When i click for the first time on my link, nothing happen. On the second click, my link work. here is my code.

```
aplication_helper.rb
def link_to_share(name, url)
  link_to_function(name, "share_link(name, url)")
end
```

my jquery file

```
function share_link(link, url)
{
  $(link).click(function() {

    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+ url, 'popupwindow', 'height=430,width=500')
  });
}
```

my view

```
<%= link_to_share 'Share', request.url %>
```

If i change my jquery function like

```
function share_link(link, url)
{
  $(link).live('click', function() {

    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+ url, 'popupwindow', 'height=430,width=500')
  });
}
```

the script stop working.

in my Firebug debugger, i have no error on the first click, and in the second try with the live function, no error too.

I use jquery-uij from gemfile.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your code work, remove the click handler

```
$(link).live('click', function() {
}
```

And just leave

```
function share_link(link, url)
{
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+ url, 'popupwindow', 'height=430,width=500')
}
```

You don't need to define the click handler, because you're using the link_to_function helper. The link_to_function helper, just calls the function you entered when you click that link.

For more information, check out the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-link_to_function). I didn't know about this helper, thanks for asking this question.

Comment: oh Great!! Thats work now! its just because the helper or the function declaration? and thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Is *nothing at all* happening or is the event handler being invoked but the window is not being opened?  It could be an officious pop-up blocker.  Put an `alert()` in the function to find out.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, the problem is not completely resolved. i will post update in my main topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
function share_link(link, url)
{
  $(link).click(function() {

    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+ url, 'popupwindow', 'height=430,width=500')
  });
}
```

the problem with that code is that it adds the listener after the click event has occurred. So the reason nothing happens the first time is that there is no event handler yet. But on the 2nd click you are calling the event handler created with the first click. See if you can rework your code to maybe take share_link as the event handler function itself.

```
function share_link(event)
{
 ...
}
$(link).click(share_link);
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help, if i want to use click handler, i need to get it out of the function declaration. thanks again!